# Field is not writeable: SkillRequirement.RelatedRecordId

Tags: field-service-lightning

I created Apex Trigger to check if SkillRequirement on Work Order and related Work Type are same or different if some field is changed on Work Order.
Sometimes SkillRequirement on WorkType has been changed and existing Work Order does not match SkillRequirement with WorkType.

But the error `Field is not writeable: SkillRequirement.RelatedRecordId` is occurred.
Please advise me how to fix the error, or an alternative way. Thank you.

```
trigger updateSkillRequrementsOnWorkOrder on WorkOrder (after update) {
    for(WorkOrder wo : trigger.new) {
        // Get WorkOrder's SkillRequirements
        List<SkillRequirement> woSr = [SELECT SkillId, RelatedRecordId FROM SkillRequirement WHERE RelatedRecordId =: wo.Id];
        // Get WorkType Skill Requirements
        List<SkillRequirement> wtSr = [SELECT SkillId, RelatedRecordId FROM SkillRequirement WHERE RelatedRecordId =: wo.WorkTypeId];
        Boolean isSame = True;
        if(wtSr.size() > 0 && woSr.size() > 0) {
            for(Integer i=0; i<woSr.size(); i++) {
                for(Integer j=0; j<wtSr.size(); j++) {
                    // compare Work Order Skill Id and Work Type Skill Id
                    if(woSr.get(i).SkillId != wtSr.get(j).SkillId) {
                        isSame = False;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(!isSame) {
            try {
                delete woSr;
                List<SkillRequirement> data = new List<SkillRequirement>();
                for(SkillRequirement tmpWtSr : wtSr) {
                    data.add(tmpWtSr);
                }
                for(Integer i=0; i<data.size(); i++) {
                    data.get(i).RelatedRecordId = woSr.get(0).RelatedRecordId;
                }
                insert data;
            } catch (DmlException e){
                System.debug('error');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.field_service_dev.meta/field_service_dev/sforce_api_objects_skillrequirement.htm) it appears that the relatedrecordid does not support **update**.

> RelatedRecordId: Properties - Create, Filter, Group, Sort

However, you can **Insert** a new record. So, instead of updating the RelatedRecordId , you could [clone](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_clone) and then insert the record. You could delete the previous copy either before inserting the clone or after inserting the clone (I tested the before scenario even without **deep-clone** and it was able to insert the cloned version of sobject.

Following lines appear unnecessary though,

`List<SkillRequirement> data = new List<SkillRequirement>();`
You could have performed the operation on `wtSr` list itself, that way you would be able to avoid

- an extra assignment
- an extra for-loop

You could something like this

```
SkillRequirement sr = [SELECT Id FROM SkillRequirement WHERE Id='someid']; // this could be wtSR (worktype skillreq list)
SkillRequirement sr2 = sr.Clone(false,false,false,false);
sr2.RelatedRecordId = [updatedID];

// delete old record
delete sr;
// insert the updated record
insert sr2;
```

I am not pasting the whole solution, I am just giving the path to the solution. Hope it helps. :D